# How can I disable already selected search bar list in input text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="medicineSearchBar" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>
      <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
      <ul style="width:100%; max-height:300px; overflow-y: scroll;" id="li-psearch" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
        <li role="presentation" class="divider-search"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to disable already selected search bar list in input text box? I’m not using any submit button and I should be done on click on search bar text input.

The data is coming from JSON file.

Comment: Are you trying to disable the input on click?

Answer (score 0):

1st, make a disable class in your css :

```
.disabled {
pointer-events:none; //This makes it not clickable
opacity:0.6; //This grays it out to look disabled
}
```

2nd, make jquery listener event for your li :

```
$(".card").on("click", "li.divider-search", function(){
$(this).addClass("disabled");
});
```